# Sencha Touch forms not usable when created with Ext.create

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have this:

```
my.Settings = {
    id: 'settings',
    xtype: 'panel',
    title: 'Settings',
    iconCls: 'settings',
    layout: 'card',
    items:[
        my.form1,
        my.form2
    ]
};
```

When `my.form1` is a config object, the form is visible and clickable (inputs allow entry, selects bring up dropdown options, etc.).

However, when I try to use `Ext.define` and `Ext.create`, the form appears visually, but nothing is selectable. If I use a tabpanel, the tabs aren't clickable, and on forms inputs won't focus or bring up the keyboard, and don't seem to respond to input at all.

Here's how I tried it:

```
Ext.define('my.form1', {
extend: 'Ext.form.Panel'
config:{...}
}
```

...

```
items: [
   Ext.create('my.form1',{id: 'myForm1'})
]
```

What about the second method causes the form to break? I'm trying to move toward using `require` and `Ext.create` for dynamic loading, but I can't do this if I can't get the simplest case working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you set the current active item? Because you use the card layout:

```
var panel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
layout: 'card',
items: [
    {
        html: "First Item"
    },
    {
        html: "Second Item"
    },
    {
        html: "Third Item"
    },
    {
        html: "Fourth Item"
    }
]
});
// here we set the active item to show on the screen
panel.getLayout().setActiveItem(1);
```

See http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.layout.Card for more information.

Comment: I did not; this could be the problem. I wonder why this would work when only using config objects, though.